# MySQL - #1005 - Can't create table 'university.Enrolment' (errno: 150) (Details…)

Tags: mysql, database

I don't know why it won't let me create the table enrolment. I only need to reference student, uniadmin and course and I have created them above enrolment.

They are all the same name, attribute type and length, so I don't know what is incorrect here. It's happening to all of the tables I use foreign key references in... so it must be something to do with them I would assume.

Error I receive:
SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE Enrolment(

EnrolmentIDCHAR( 3 ) NOT NULL ,
StudentIDCHAR( 3 ) NOT NULL ,
StaffIDCHAR( 3 ) NOT NULL ,
CourseIDCHAR( 7 ) NOT NULL ,
CampusCHAR( 2 ) NOT NULL ,
Trimester TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL ,
CONSTRAINT PK_Enrolment PRIMARY KEY ( EnrolmentID ) ,
CONSTRAINT FK1_Enrolment FOREIGN KEY ( StudentID ) REFERENCES Student( StudentID ) ,
CONSTRAINT FK2_Enrolment FOREIGN KEY ( StaffID ) REFERENCES UniversityAdmin( StaffID ) ,
CONSTRAINT FK3_Enrolment FOREIGN KEY ( CourseID ) REFERENCES Course( CourseID ) ,
CONSTRAINT FK4_Enrolment FOREIGN KEY ( Campus ) REFERENCES Course( Campus ) ,
CONSTRAINT FK5_Enrolment FOREIGN KEY ( Trimester ) REFERENCES Course( Trimester ) /*constraint Check_EnrolmentCampus check (Campus in ('GC', 'BR')*/
);

MySQL said: Documentation

#1005 - Can't create table 'university.Enrolment' (errno: 150) (Details…)
```

"Details" says:

InnoDB  Documentation

Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys

[ Variables | Buffer Pool | InnoDB Status ]

My code:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS university;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS university;
USE university;

drop table if exists Student;
drop table if exists UniversityAdmin;
drop table if exists Course;
drop table if exists Academic;
drop table if exists Teaches;
drop table if exists Administers;
drop table if exists Manages;
drop table if exists Enrolment;
drop table if exists Scored;

Create table Student(
            StudentID Char(3) not null,
            Password Varchar(20) not null,
            FirstName Varchar(15) not null,
            MiddleName Varchar(15),
            LastName Varchar(15) not null,
            DateOfBirth Date not null,
            Sex Char(1) not null,
            HomeAddress Varchar(60) not null,
            PhoneNumber Varchar(10) not null,
            constraint PK_Student primary key(StudentID)
            /*constraint Check_StudentSex check (Sex in ('M', 'F')*/
            );

Create table UniversityAdmin(
            StaffID Char(3) not null,
            Password Varchar(20) not null,
            Duty Varchar(20) not null,
            FirstName Varchar(15) not null,
            MiddleName Varchar(15),
            LastName Varchar(15) not null,
            DateOfBirth Date not null,
            Sex Char(1) not null,
            HomeAddress Varchar(60) not null,
            PhoneNumber Varchar(10) not null,
            constraint PK_UniversityAdmin primary key(StaffID)
            /*constraint Check_UniversityAdminSex check (Sex in ('M', 'F')*/
            );

Create table Course(
            CourseID Char(7) not null,
            Campus Char(2) not null,
            Trimester TinyInt(1) not null,
            CourseName Varchar(50) not null,
            Convenor Varchar(30) not null,
            Prerequisite Char(7),
            Year TinyInt(4) not null,
            constraint PK_Course primary key(CourseID, Campus, Trimester)
            /*constraint Check_CourseCampus check (Campus in ('GC', 'BR')*/
            );

Create table Academic(
            StaffID Char(3) not null,
            Password Varchar(20) not null,
            Position Varchar(30) not null,
            FirstName Varchar(15) not null,
            MiddleName Varchar(15),
            LastName Varchar(15) not null,
            DateOfBirth Date not null,
            Sex Char(1) not null,
            HomeAddress Varchar(60) not null,
            PhoneNumber Varchar(10) not null,
            constraint PK_Academic primary key(StaffID)
            /*constraint Check_AcademicSex check (Sex in ('M', 'F')*/
            );      

Create table Enrolment(
            EnrolmentID Char(3) not null,
            StudentID Char(3) not null,
            StaffID Char(3) not null,
            CourseID Char(7) not null,
            Campus Char(2) not null,
            Trimester TinyInt(1) not null,
            constraint PK_Enrolment primary key (EnrolmentID),
            constraint FK1_Enrolment foreign key (StudentID) references Student(StudentID),
            constraint FK2_Enrolment foreign key (StaffID) references UniversityAdmin(StaffID),
            constraint FK3_Enrolment foreign key (CourseID) references Course(CourseID),
            constraint FK4_Enrolment foreign key (Campus) references Course(Campus),
            constraint FK5_Enrolment foreign key (Trimester) references Course(Trimester)
            /*constraint Check_EnrolmentCampus check (Campus in ('GC', 'BR')*/
            );
```

Comment: post the error you get

Comment: I updated with my error message

Comment: click on details and post the complete error

Comment: I posted what "details" said. I am using codeanywhere for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already created the others tables you can alter the `Course` table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Course
      ADD INDEX(Campus),
      ADD INDEX(Trimester);
```

Like this you can use those two columns like foreign keys in your  `Enrolment` table,otherwise you will get an error while creating this table.

If you want to delete the table `Course` you have to delete `Enrolment` first , after adding the foreign keys.

Comment: It worked!! Buy I don't understand why. What does adding those two indexs do? I thought you only needed indexes when you reference a FK which isnt a primary key?